# How to Set Varnish Cache-Control Headers

Tags: http-headers, cache-control, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am hoping someone can advise on the proper method for getting Varnish to send cache-control headers. Currently, my configuration is sending **"Cache-Control: no-cache"** to clients.

Thanks in advance to anyone who might be able to help...

Comment: It might help if you explain what you want. Which configuration (varnish or your back-end) is sending no-cache headers? You can override these headers in Varnish, but whether this is 'correct' depends on the semantics of your responses (are they reusable, over clients, for how long, etc).

Comment: @ivy, Thanks for your reply. What I am trying to accomplish is to have **Varnish** send cache-control headers which I manually specify, regardless of what the back-end sends to Varnish.

Answer (score 15):

Your back-end is sending "Cache-Control: no-cache" to Varnish which implies two things:

- Varnish will not store the response in the cache (so a next lookup will fail)
- Your clients (browsers and intermediate proxies) will not cache responses (and request them over and over).

The solution is simple: remove the cache-control headers after fetching the response from the back-end (and before storing them in the cache).

In your vcl file do:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  remove beresp.http.Cache-Control;
  set beresp.http.Cache-Control = "public";
}
```

You can choose to only do this for certain urls (wrap it in `( if req.url ~ "" )` logic) and do way more advanced stuff.

Comment: As of Varnish 4.0 `vcl_fetch` was replaced with `vcl_backend_response`

Comment: As of Varnish 6.5  `remove` was replaced with `unset`

Answer (score 4):

Varnish ignores Cache-Control: nocache as per the documentation.  Here is evidence confirming that:

http://drupal.org/node/1418908

To get that result, you should detect the header Cache-Control .*nocache.* from your backend, and then invalidate the cache, set the backend response to not cacheable, or issue max-age: 0 in the other header (I forget the name right now).

Comment: This issue is now closed. I think the poster realized he made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

[ivy] has good advice, and/but it gets a little complicated when you try to obey a servers intent for end user (browser) caching. I found [this resource](https://web.archive.org/web/20120114043834/https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleLongerCaching) to be helpful in understanding a way to configure Varnish to hold onto a cache longer than a browser is instructed to...

[https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleLongerCaching](https://web.archive.org/web/20120114043834/https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleLongerCaching)