# PHP Session Id Reset on page load

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I've looked at everything here and elsewhere, nothing seems to work!

Here's the issue:

- On page load, upon calling `session_start()`, I get assigned a PHP session ID.
- Once I refresh the page, I get a new session ID and that makes the `$_SESSION` variable come empty.

PHP Version is: `5.6.30-0+deb8u1`

I did a small script to replicate outside of the application:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo '<pre>';
echo 'orig session.cookie_domain = '.ini_get('session.cookie_domain').PHP_EOL;
echo 'orig session.cookie_secure = '.ini_get('session.cookie_secure').PHP_EOL;
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mydomain.com');
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 'Off');
echo 'new session.cookie_domain = '.ini_get('session.cookie_domain').PHP_EOL;
echo 'new session.cookie_secure = '.ini_get('session.cookie_secure').PHP_EOL;
echo '-------------'.PHP_EOL;
print_r($_COOKIE);
session_start();
print_r($_COOKIE);
setcookie(ini_get('session.name'), session_id(), 0, '/', ini_get('session.cookie_domain'), false, false);
print_r($_COOKIE);
echo '-------------'.PHP_EOL;
echo 'session id: '.session_id().PHP_EOL;
echo '-------------'.PHP_EOL;
$_SESSION[session_id()][] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
//phpinfo();
```

output of script is:

```
orig session.cookie_domain = 
orig session.cookie_secure = 
new session.cookie_domain = .mydomain.com
new session.cookie_secure = Off
-------------
Array
(
    [__cfduid] => ddxxx
    [_ga] => GA1.2.xxxx
    [wp-settings-time-2] => 1500996194
    [_gid] => GA1.3.xxxx
)
Array
(
    [__cfduid] => ddxxx
    [_ga] => GA1.2.xxxx
    [wp-settings-time-2] => 1500996194
    [_gid] => GA1.3.xxxx
)
Array
(
    [__cfduid] => ddxxx
    [_ga] => GA1.2.xxxx
    [wp-settings-time-2] => 1500996194
    [_gid] => GA1.3.xxxx
)
-------------
session id: 7n4mm16s525mpqo99r242p90l3
-------------
Array
(
    [7n4mm16s525mpqo99r242p90l3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2017-08-07 16:01:18
        )

)
```

Comment: Sounds like your domain isn't set correctly. What's the actual domain you're using compared to the one you've set?

Comment: And what URL are you going to in your browser? Do you actually need to set cookie_domain? What's your use-case to not just use the host?

Comment: @JonStirling there's a staging environment on a subdomain, that's why. Not setting it does the same thing.

Comment: Hmm, unsure then. I can kind of replicate (works fine on specific domains, but not on . prefixes ones) , but not worked out how to resolve so far.

Comment: `session_start()` must be invoked before any output.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter tried putting it on line 4, does the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, it came out to be Varnish cache causing the problem. The problem lies in Varnish caching the page without session cookies set, making it useless after a refresh of the page.

**Disabling Varnish on the server solved the problem for me.**

Also found out this for those who would prefer to keep Varnish active but get sessions to work: [Cache-Control Header Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13142143/1387090)

Answer (score 0):

Do this, to preserve the existing session:

```
if(session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: still not working.. In the app, I'm also using this without success:

    if(!session_id()){
      session_start();
    }

Answer (score 0):

check is_writable(session_save_path()) in php file:

```
<?php
if (!is_writable(session_save_path())) {
    echo 'Session path "'.session_save_path().'" is not writable for PHP!';
    // you need set chmod -R 777 [session save path folder]
}
```

Hope to help you